# Visual Studio 2017 New Project missing .net core frameworks

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Anyone else have the issue where, when creating a new project no matter what new project template you select, even if it's a .net core project, the only framework options you have in the drop-down at the top are full .Net Frameworks?  If I choose a .Net Core project, it still only shows me .Net Framework 2.0 - 4.7 as options to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I guess I have a itchy finger when it comes to asking a question on SO.  When you click next, you get the option to choose framework which is weird but oh well.